# Getting Basic Information about ArcGIS Map Service With IGxDialog

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, arccatalog

I am having a helluva time trying to get some basic information (server URL) about an ArcGIS Map Service using the basic IGxDialog.

So far, I am able to pop open the IGxDialog, and allow the user to pick an ArcGIS Map Service by setting the appropriate filter(GxFilterMapServers).  Thats about as far as I can make it.  What should I cast pGxObj to so I can more info about the map service?

```
IGxDialog pGxDialog = new GxDialog();
pGxDialog.AllowMultiSelect = false;
pGxDialog.Title = "Browse For AGIS Map Service";

IGxObjectFilter pGxFCFilter = new GxFilterMapServers();
pGxDialog.ObjectFilter = pGxFCFilter;

IEnumGxObject pGxObjects = null;
if (pGxDialog.DoModalOpen(0, out pGxObjects))
{
pGxObjects.Reset();
IGxObject pGxObj = pGxObjects.Next();
while (pGxObj != null)
{
// what do I do here to get more info about the map server???
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [IGxAGSObject](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGxAGSObject_Interface/0014000000pq000000/).

```
if (pGxObj is IGxAGSObject)
{
    var agsObj = pGxObj as IGxAGSObject;
    object names;
    object values;
    agsObj.AGSServerObjectName.AGSServerConnectionName.ConnectionProperties.GetAllProperties(out names, out values);
    var n = names as string[];
    var o = values as object[];
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<n.Length;i++)
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}",n[i],o[i].ToString()));
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```